# Pagination php from array

Tags: php

I've been trying to pagginate my picture but very very unssucesfull i am hopping i can ghet some hints on how to do it. This is my code.

```
<?php                                           
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY position");
   while ($image = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<img src="images/uploads/thumbs/<?php echo $image['thumb'];?>" width="100%" height="100%" alt="" class="thumbnail" />
<input type='button' value='Preview' onclick="changedesc(<?php echo $image['image_id']; ?>); return false;" />
<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This shoul'd do it..

```
  <?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY date";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while ($image = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo '
    <img src="images/uploads/thumbs/'.$image['thumb'].'" width="100%" height="100%" alt="" class="thumbnail" />
    ';
    }
    ?>
```